# "be verb" is followed after an "action verb"

Tags: verbs, modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs

I have found in [this website](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=TsrBbgMM1qgC&pg=RA1-PA33&lpg=RA1-PA33&dq=%22what+we+can+say+is+that%22&source=bl&ots=2Hk5s-cIGJ&sig=JpAZm-xVCNMiIPWATTaWzk-6H6U&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNqd3k5ODMAhUh4qYKHe0pBb8Q6AEIKzAD#v=onepage&q=%22what%20we%20can%20say%20is%20that%22&f=false) that the "state of being" or "be" verb (***is***) is followed by an "action verb" (***say***). What is the rule behind this? Please explain.

> What we can ***say is*** that this is an important issue, which the MoD should be looking at.

Comment: All I *say* is - yeah, it's possible! :P

Comment: As per your example, the phrase (I say) is an appositive of "All". However it is different in my criterion, the word "What" is not a noun (I assume). If the phrase "we can say" is an appositive "What", "What" would have become as an interrogative pronoun which should end with question mark.

Comment: This sentence is an ordinary *X is Y* copulation, with a [free relative clause](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free-relative-clauses) as its subject. Parse it like this: *[What we can say] is [that this is an important issue].*

Comment: See No. 2 definition and the first example sentence. ['*What we need is a commitment*'](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/what)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure is "[What we can say] is ... ". The two verbs are not in the same clause. "What we can say" is a subordinate clause functioning as the subject of "is".